# PHP Extract url

Tags: php, ajax, email

I have this ajax based quiz that leads to php based contact_details page after the last question is answered. Now, the answers submitted by the user on the quiz are parsed through the url of the contact_details page. Now, when the user fills up his details and clicks Submit, I need the url (answers) to the quiz too to be submitted so that I receive the email with the contact details and the answers to the ajax quiz.

Could you tell me how to capture the url so that it could be sent on submit?

Comment: So the final page has the query string?

Comment: are the quiz questions and the contact form on the same page? Then just put everything in 1 form. But I'm not sure I understood your case. Can you put up some example code, at least we should see what php files you have

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look for PHP `$_SERVER` variables:

```
$server = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]; // eg. "stackoverflow.com"
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; // eg. "/questions/19133954/php-extract-url"
```

Manual reference: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php